# Exception in plugin Android

Tags: android, gradle, nullpointerexception, fatal-error

I got this fatal error , when I was trying to import opencv module to my project.
Even Gradle sync is finished successfully,
I have also tried invalidate cache and restart but it does not solved anything.
And also went through some stackoverflow's solutions that too didn't work.

please help me finding the solution.

Error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.getBuildToolsVersion(GradleImport.java:1081)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.createModuleBuildGradle(GradleImport.java:971)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.exportModule(GradleImport.java:927)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.exportProject(GradleImport.java:792)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.AdtImportBuilder.lambda$commit$0(AdtImportBuilder.java:151)
    at 

...

java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

> Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> gradle : app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.opencv"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.10.2'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Please share your build.gradle and app.gradle file

Comment: @Younus done you can check it now

Comment: I think that this error is because of you don't import your build tool version(example:buildToolsVersion '28.0.3') in gradle: app.